# Android: Loading images from the internal folder by using String ID

Tags: android, load, android-camera, android-gallery, internal

I'm new to android programming and have been trying to figure out how to 
load an image (at startup) from the assets folder and save that image in a object (What kind of object should i save it into?)
So that when i want to display that object in an imageview i can just point to it and retreve an imageview displaying that image.
I tryed looking for similar posts but there was nothing specific enough for me to understand fully.

Is there any way to do this or is it a completely wrong approach to using images in android?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you need. It gets the AssetManager, reads a bitmap from assets, and places the bitmap in an image view.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Get the AssetManager
    AssetManager manager = getAssets();

    // Read a Bitmap from Assets
    try {
        InputStream open = manager.open("icon.png");
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(open);
        // Assign the bitmap to an ImageView in this layout
        ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
        view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

The **onCreate** method runs when the activity is created. The content view is set and then the AssetManager is retrieved. The AssetManager opens the image "icon".png and saves it as a bitmap. The bitmap can now be assigned to imageviews.